# PyQt4 default theme to current system theme change

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, themes

I'm new to PyQt, I'm going to design an UI, main problem is when i run .py file, in Qt designer default theme is system theme in both windows 10 and debian 8 but after run .py in linux an ugly theme will be shown, i want to have current system theme style after compiling python.

PyQt4.11.1, Qt Designer 5.3, Debian 8.

Current System Theme

[image]

PyQt4 classic theme

[image]

Comment: What is your development machine? Windows 10 or Debian 8 or something else?

Comment: PyQt4.11.1, Qt Designer 5.3, Debian 8.

Comment: in windows 10 default theme is system that is ok, but in debian default theme is not system current theme.

Comment: Have you [set the right GUI style in qt4-config](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22316/how-can-i-theme-my-qt-app-to-resemble-one-written-in-gtk) ?

Comment: it was right solution, thanks ekhumoro.